# fgets() reads char and int input but when printed it prints nonsense

Tags: c

I have a program that puts vehicles in the form of structs into an array and saves it to a file. I want to use malloc to dynamically allocate memory for the array so that vehicles can be deleted if needed. I use fgets() to take information about the vehicles and I input characters and numbers into the struct but when i try to print it and also in the file where i save them it looks like nonsense numbers and symbols. What could be the issue?

Here is the code for the functions:

This one takes information about the vehicles, the counter counts how many vehicles are currently in the file and starts at 1 and increases every time i save a new vehicle.

```
//Lägg till ett fordon
 void add(int counter, fordon_t reg[])
{
    reg=(fordon_t *)malloc(counter*sizeof(fordon_t));
    printf("Fordonstyp:");
    fgets(reg[counter].type, SIZE-1, stdin);
    strtok(reg[counter].type, "\n");
    printf("Märke:");
    fgets(reg[counter].brand, SIZE-1, stdin);
    strtok(reg[counter].brand, "\n");
    printf("Registreringsnummer:");
    fgets(reg[counter].regnum, SIZE-1, stdin);
    strtok(reg[counter].regnum, "\n");
    printf("Ägare:\nFörnamn:");
    fgets(reg[counter].owner.firstname, SIZE-1, stdin);
    strtok(reg[counter].owner.firstname, "\n");
    printf("Efternamn:");
    fgets(reg[counter].owner.lastname, SIZE-1, stdin);
    strtok(reg[counter].owner.lastname, "\n");
    do{
        printf("Ålder:");
        char tmp[SIZE];
        fgets(tmp, SIZE-1, stdin);
        strtok(tmp, "\n");
        reg[counter].owner.age = atoi(tmp);
        if (reg[counter].owner.age == 0)
        {
            printf("Var god och skriv en siffra\n");
        }
    }   
    while(reg[counter].owner.age == 0);
    free(reg);
}
```

This one prints the entire list of vehicles:

```
//Skriv ut hela registret
void print_all(int counter, fordon_t reg[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<counter; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %s %d %s %s %s\n", reg[i].owner.firstname, reg[i].owner.lastname, reg[i].owner.age, reg[i].type, reg[i].brand, reg[i].regnum);
    }
}
```

Comment: `fgets(reg[counter].type, SIZE-1, stdin);` The `counter` value is not a valid array index. For an array of size `counter` elements the valid array indices are `0` to `counter-1`.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you are doing : at the beginning of add() you create reg array with counter elements. At the end you delete it. So after add() is done you have nothing in memory.